Operator strong $(p,p)$ implies adjoint strong $(p',p')$
Let $T$ be a linear and continuous operator $T: L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{d}) \to L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{d})$. I wonder to what extent we can conclude if $T$ is strong $(p,p)$, we will obtain that $T'$, the adjoint of $T$, is strong $(p', p')$. For simplicity, we can take strong $(p,p)$ to be restricted to $S(\mathbb{R}^{d})$, that is if $T$ is strong $(p,p)$ iff $\|Tf\|_{L^{p}}\leq \|f\|_{L^{p}}$ for shwarz function $f$.
I think to show $T'$ is strong $(p',p')$ is a duality argument, but I cannot pin down some very specific details, basically have $\sup_{\|f\|_{p}=1, f \text{ simple, compact support}} \langle f, T^{'}g \rangle = \|T^{'}g\|_{p'}$, but this requires $T^{'}g$ to be locally $L^{1}$ integrable, and I guess for the supremum to be finite. If we have $T'(g)$ is shwarz for any function $g$, then of course we have this conclusion by some simple manipulation, but I don't think we can assume that.
Basically, I'm just not very certain what is the exact statement one can make in this circumstance and what needs to be assumed. I saw this in the theory of Calderon Zygmund operator, where from $T$ being strong $(p,p)$ for $1< p< 2$, we have $T'$ is strong $(p',p')$.

Isn’t this just the combination of the fact that the adjoint of a bounded map is bounded and that the dual of $L^p$ is $L^{p’}$?

@peek-a-boo Yes, roughly. I'm just not very certain about the precise statement. Here you would need to consider $T: L^{2} \cap L^{p} \to L^{2} \cap L^{p}$. where I'm not exactly certain with the dual of $L^{2} \cap L^{p}$. I'm not experienced in functional analysis with adjoints in these areas.

$L^2\cap L^p$ is dense in $L^p$ (for all $1<p<\infty$) so $T$ extends to a unique bounded linear map $\widetilde{T}:L^p\to L^p$, and now apply my first comment.

@peek-a-boo Just to make sure I understand this correctly, so we have $T:L^{2} \to L^{2}$, and the adjoint $T^{}:L^{2} \to L^{2}$, and if we restrict $T$ to $L^{2} \cap L^{p}$, where $1\leq p<\infty$, and complete it to the operator $\tilde{T}:L^{p} \to L^{p}$, then the adjoint $\tilde{T}^{}$ is the same as $T^{}$ restricted to $L^{2} \cap L^{p'}$ and completed to $L^{p'}$, and this is true as the adjoint applied to the shwarz function is the same. Then $T: L^{2}  \to L^{2}$, is strong $(p,p)$, implies that $T^{}$ is strong $(p', p')$ for $1\leq p<\infty$. is my understanding correct?
